# Setting up Selenium Grid 4 across multiple machines using docker-compose

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, docker-compose, debian, selenium-grid

I am trying to setup a Selenium Grid (4.16.1 revision 9b4c83354e) in a hub and node architecture using docker compose across two bare metal servers on the same internal network.  The servers are running Debian 12 and UFW with settings to allow all internal network traffic.  I am trying to use docker-compose on both machines to set up a hub on one machine (machine1) that can leverage nodes on localhost and on the other bare metal server (machine2) on the local network.  The Hub and nodes on machine1 connect fine and show up on the grid; however when I start nodes on machine2 they do not connect to the hub on machine1.

I have seen several questions on stackoverflow about this with only one suggestion of using docker swarm. I suspect I am overlooking something trivial but I can't for the life of me figure out what I am missing.

Sample .yml from physical machine1 running the hub and nodes:

```
version: "3"
services:
  hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4442:4442"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: 3gb
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=1
    ports:
      - 5901:5900
```

Sample .yml from physical machine2 running the additional nodes:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:latest
    shm_size: 3gb
    environment:
      - NODE_GRID_URL=http://192.168.1.xxx:4444 #machine1 ip
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=192.168.1.xxx #machine1 ip
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=1
      - SE_NODE_HOST=192.168.1.yyy #machine2 ip

    ports:
      - 6901:5900
```

I have also tried HUB=http://192.168.1.xxx:4444 and HUB=http://192.168.1.xxx:4444/grid/register in the place of NODE_GRID_URL=http://192.168.1.xxx:4444 with no luck.

Appreciate any help and will provide further clarification if needed.